# logging request/response bytes size in tonic server

Tags: performance, rust

I have a tonic server, for which I already have implemented a tower_layer which monitors request latency (summary of code below, in case it's useful).

I need to add monitoring for bytes received/sent per endpoint.

RequestBody should eventually resolve into something that implements `prost::Message` (see below) and therefore has an `encoded_len` method. I couldn't find an implementation for this method but I'm guessing it requires consuming the message in order to get the length, so in theory I guess I could somehow patch `tonic::Request::into_inner()` and log the length there... but I think this is obviously a worse solution.

Another option I guess might be to add this logging on the client side, but I'd also prefer to avoid that.

What I mean is, I'd like to be able to log the both the request and response sizes in the same layer, but I can't figure out how to do it using the same tools I've made for latency monitoring.

```
impl<T, RequestBody, ResponseBody: 'static> Service<tonic::codegen::http::Request<RequestBody>>
    for EndpointTimer<T>
where
    T: Service<
            tonic::codegen::http::Request<RequestBody>,
            Response = tonic::codegen::http::Response<ResponseBody>,
        > + Send,
    T::Future: Send + 'static,
    T::Error: Into<Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> + 'static,
    T::Response: 'static,
{
    type Response = T::Response;
    type Error = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>> + Send>>;

    fn poll_ready(...) { ... }

    fn call(&mut self, req: tonic::codegen::http::Request<RequestBody>) -> Self::Future {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let future = self.inner.call(req);
        let timed_future = async move {
            let res = future.await;
            // ... time and log the duration
            res.map_err(|err| err.into())
        };
        Box::pin(timed_future)
    }
}

// A layer for wrapping services in `EndpointTimer`
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct EndpointTimerLayer();

impl EndpointTimerLayer {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        EndpointTimerLayer()
    }
}

impl<S> Layer<S> for EndpointTimerLayer {
    type Service = EndpointTimer<S>;

    fn layer(&self, service: S) -> EndpointTimer<S> {
        EndpointTimer::new(service)
    }
}
```

EDIT

I've looked more into this, and I'm pretty sure it's not possible. The generated server code (in `target`) looks like

```
impl<T, B> tonic::codegen::Service<http::Request<B>> for MyServer<T>
    where [...]
    {
        [...]
        fn call(&mut self, req: http::Request<B>) -> Self::Future {
            [...]
            match req.uri().path() {
                "/my_service.MyServiceProvider/MyEndpoint" => {
                    [...]
                    let fut = async move {
                        [...]
                        let res = grpc.unary(method, req).await;
                        Ok(res)
                    };
                    Box::pin(fut)
                }
```

which calls tonic code here: https://docs.rs/tonic/latest/src/tonic/server/grpc.rs.html#153

which winds up streaming the request here: https://docs.rs/tonic/latest/src/tonic/server/grpc.rs.html#280

now, I have had the thought of attempting to overload into_parts for `http::Request`, so that it also sends request size to prometheus, because self.body in this case is `tonic::Request` which has the `into_inner` method which returns the `prost::Message` that has `encoded_len()`.

But I don't think it's possible, because neither `http::Request::into_parts` nor `tonic::Request::into_inner` are a trait implementation: https://docs.rs/http/latest/src/http/request.rs.html#668

Comment: I think your `Service` level is too high. You need to intercept the outermost service at https://docs.rs/axum-server/latest/axum_server/struct.Server.html#method.serve

Comment: I don't think I understand how to do this, could you elaborate?